# How to change oil in Aprilia Atlantic 500?

Tags: oil-change, scooter, aprilia

I am about to change oil in my Aprilia Atlantic 500.
I don't have a manual (BTW I am looking for one).

How do I change oil?

Comment: I have found a [Polish video specifically with Atlantic 500](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1aqnLzFrLk). Adding as an answer if it helps someone.

Comment: Changed your answer to a comment since it's a "link only" answer, which are really frowned upon here on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the instructions from [this page](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/800034/Aprilia-Atlantic-500.html?page=42):

> ENGINE OIL CHANGE AND OIL FILTER
>
> Check the level of the engine oil every 1,875 miles(3,000 km), see
>   (CHECKING THE ENGINE OIL LEVEL AND TOPPING UP).
>
> **NOTE**
>
> Use oil with 5/W 40 specifications, see (LUBRICANT CHART).
>
> **When topping up engine oil, we recommend that you never exceed the "MAX" level.**
>
> It is necessary to check the engine oil after the first 625 miles
>   (1,000 km) and then:–every 3,750 miles (6,000 km) replace oil.–every
>   1,875 miles (3,000 km) check level/top up.
>
> **NOTE**  Place the vehicle on a flat, hard surface.
>
> - Place the vehicle on the center stand.
>
> **WARNING**
>
> **The engine and exhaust system components become very hot, and remain hot for some time even after the engine has been shut off. Before
>   handling these components, wear insulating gloves or wait until the
>   engine and exhaust system have cooled down.**
>
> - Stop the engine and let it cool, to allow the oil to drain into the half-case and cool.
>
> **NOTE** If you do not carry out the previous operations, you risk taking an incorrect measurement of the engine oil level.
>
> - Unscrew and extract the cap-dipstick (1).
> - Unscrew and remove the engine oil cartridge filter(3).
>
> [image]
>
> **WARNING**
>
> **Never use the vehicle with insufficient lubrication or with contaminated or inappropriate lubricants,as these accelerate wear on
>   moving parts and may cause irreparable damage.**
>
> **WARNING**
>
> **The oil used contains substances hazardous to the environment; therefore, to change the engine oil contact an aprilia dealer, who
>   will dispose of the used oil in compliance with current regulations.**
>
> [image]
>
> - Unscrew and remove the oil drain plug (4) and let all of the engine oil flow out.
> - Install a new oil cartridge filter (3), being careful to lubricate the O-ring gaskets on the filter with oil.
> - Tighten the engine oil drain plug (4).
> - Fill through the filling hole (2) with approximately 103.7 cu.in (1700 cc) of engine oil.
> - Tighten the oil level dipstick (1).
> - Start the vehicle and let it run for a few minutes.Shut it off and let it cool. Check the engine oil level again using the dipstick (1),
>     and top up if necessary, without ever exceeding the "MAX" level.
>
> **When topping up and changing oil, use new oil ofthe type 5W-40 synthetic oil SAE that exceeds API ST specifications.**

Comment: Great! Thanks for the link, all I could find was Italian.

Comment: @Paulster2   Many thanks for that manualslib link.  Never seen that before.  Wow.

Comment: @zipzit - My Google Fu must be strong :o)

Answer (score 1):

A generic answer : drain oil into a container, measure the volume.

Put that amount of fresh oil back into engine - remembering to refit drain plug first :) then check level and top up if necessary .

Run engine, check drain plug not leaking, then stop engine and wait 5 minutes then check level again and top up if necessary.